# Can someone make me understand what the issue really is here? new to django

Tags: django, class, django-rest-framework

I am using *django==3.2*

**I forced this error:**

`AssertionError at /api/content/coordinator/read/0`
The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not                                  content_delivery.view.coordinator.Coordinator_View.

This is my code:

```
class Coordinator_View(object):

    @staticmethod
    def run(request):
        obj = Coordinator_View()
        return obj.create(request) # this is where the actual error happens

    @api_view(['POST'])
    def create(self, request):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved]
Rather than trying to use or make custom class for class based views, what I did was inherit either View class or API_View class according to the requirements. Inheriting all the behaviors of those parent class reduces the amount of work by a factor of 0.8.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you handle views in django. You should create a method that returns an HttpResponse Object. Also, note that "render()" function is a shortcut function that django uses to create a HttpResponse Object.
Example :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def example_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    var = 'some value'
    context = {
        'var': var
    }

    return render(request, 'template_path', context=context)
```

Basic version:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def other_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("some text")
```

Also, make sure your 'urls.py' are setup correctly, you need to point django to a correct view inside of 'urls.py'.

Comment: Unless you really want to use class-based views, in which case, disregard my answer. However, it's much more complicated and unless you're creating a very big project I'm not sure why would you do it.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment, I have completed the project in normal procedural way, just was experimenting to migrate it to full OO. will keep your advice in mind